# Unable to execute URL Scheme in MicroStrategy iPad App from React JS MicroStrategy Widget

Tags: reactjs, ipad, url-scheme, microstrategy

I have developed a widget/plugin using the React JS framework for MicroStrategy.
The objective is to call a specific URL using URL scheme from within the MicroStrategy iPad app.
However, the URL scheme is not functioning as expected. When attempting to call the URL using the specified scheme, it does not get triggered, and if I try to use the HTTPS protocol, the app opens the URL in the browser instead.

Below is the code which I am trying:

```
function onExit() {
const mstrMainURL = 'mstr:\\Main.aspx?evt=2048001&documentID=123456&currentViewMedia=1&visMode=0';
window.location.assign(mstrMainURL);}
```